# What’s causing the syntax error in the IF EXISTS line in my SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I’m running this SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM score WHERE username='ms')
UPDATE score SET score='30' WHERE username='ms'
ELSE 
INSERT INTO score (username,score) VALUES ('ms','30')
```

but I keep getting this syntax error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM score WHERE username='ms') UPDATE score SET score='30'` at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to run this in your *phpmyadmin* SQL environment. That should give you more information. However `IF` statements can only be used in `stored procedures` and `functions` on MySQL

Comment: Could you give whole procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4205181)

Comment: @ Mouser Sir, the error details i posted is the result  i  run  in my phpmyadmin.

Comment: @mario sir,i run INSERT INTO score (username,score) VALUES ('ms','30') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score SET score='30' WHERE username='ms',returns #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET score='30' WHERE username='ms'' at line 1, still syntax error

Comment: @mario thank you very much! it did solve the problems but i still don't know why my code had syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` as control flow is only allowed in programming blocks in stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  This should not be confused with the function `if()`, a non-standard MySQL extension that is allowed in any expression.

However, you can do what you want using `replace` or `on duplicate key update`.  First, create a unique index on `username`:

```
create unique index idx_score_username on score(username);
```

Then do the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO score (username, score)
    VALUES ('ms', 30)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = VALUES(score);
```

Note that I removed the single quotes from `'30'`.  If `score1` is numeric (a reasonable assumption I think), then use a numeric constant rather than a string constant.